# zkemsdk sdk unlock door for a particular time

Tags: c#

I have implemented one programme to unlock the Biometric Door using zkemsdk . I am able to unlock the door but after 5 sec it's automatically locked.I s there any way to unlock the door for a particular time? I need to open the lock for 1hr My code follows (c#) I have changed the value of dely but no effect.O r is there any way to start or shutdown the device?

```
CZKEM objDevice = new CZKEM();
int Delay = 0;
if (objDevice.Connect_Net(punchMachineIP, Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PUNCH_MACHINE_PORT"])))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Device : " + punchMachineIP);

    machineNumber = objDevice.MachineNumber;

    objDevice.RefreshData(machineNumber);
    objDevice.EnableDevice(machineNumber, false);//disable the Device

    if (objDevice.ACUnlock(machineNumber,Delay))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("unlock success");
    }

     objDevice.EnableDevice(machineNumber, true);//enable the Device

      objDevice.Disconnect();
    objDevice.RefreshData(machineNumber);
 }
```

Comment: What little documentation I've been able to find suggests that the `Delay` parameter of the `ACUnlock()` method controls how long the door is unlocked for, but it didn't mention what units were used. What values have you tried setting it to?

Comment: I had tried multiples  values like 20 ,50 but it will automatically lock after 10 sec

Comment: *If* it's using milliseconds as the unit you might want to try higher values, such as `60000` for a minute etc

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: @justintjacob Are you using zkemkeeper.dll or zkemsdk.dll? Is it possible to use the sdk without registering it with regsvr32 to system32 folder?